# Defining the exponential prior with jumping order of magnitude in parameter space

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc, pymc3

I want to define an Exponential prior for a parameter as following

[image]

Therefore I have defined it in pymc with

```
@pm.stochastic
def MASS(value=math.pow(10,15), rate = math.pow(10,15)):
    """mass is a stochastic parameter with exponential distribution.p(M)~exp(-M/10^15)"""
    return pm.exponential_like(value, rate)
@pm.potential
def MASS_bound(MASS=MASS):
    if ((MASS >= math.pow(10,13)) and (MASS < math.pow(10,16))):
       return 0.0
    else:
       return -np.inf
```

I also want it to satisfy the constraint that

[image]

But what happened when I run my MCMC code `MASS` changes very slowly while I would like it to change in this three order of magnitude faster between `1e+13` and `1e16`. How could I define my prior in order to change considerable in the parameter space?

Comment: I don't know how to use pymc, but I think what you want is to sample in `log(M)` rather than `M` itself.

Comment: Also: use `1e13` and `1e15` rather than `math.pow(10,13)` and `math.pow(10,15)`.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe If I use an uniform prior and set the upper limit and lower limit to `1e16` and `1e13` according to pymc documentation it would have the problem of not moving fast in the parameter space properly and best solution is an exponential but I don't know how to define it to also not get stuck in the huge order of magnitude changes.

Comment: I may be completely misunderstanding, but I think you've got it exactly backwards. You want a uniform prior in `log M` and hence `P(M) = 1/M` (up to a const. of proportionality). This means that the decade 1e12 to 1e13 will come up as often as the decade 1e13 to 1e14 and 1e14 to 1e15.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe Well I saw your profile and you are a cosmologist. So if I want to define my prior on the mass of galaxy cluster's halos and it follows simulated and observed mass function, should its probability follow the before-mentioned type of exponential probability and probably `log P(M)=-M/1e15`?

Comment: Aha, I didn't realise that's what you were doing. So indeed you do want something like an exponential distribution (possibly multiplied by a power-law in the mass?). But now I'm not sure what you actually want to do. There is much more probability (more halos) of low mass than high, so you will get more samples there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founs that the prior would look like exponential if I define it between `[1e-2,10]` range and then in order to use it in the log-likelihood just multiply it with `1e15` to obtain the desired order of amplitude for further analysis

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
M0=1e15

@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def ma(name='ma',value=0.1, rate = 1):
    """mass is a stochastic parameter with exponential distribution.p(M)~exp(-M/10^15)"""
    return pm.exponential_like(value, rate)
@pm.potential
def ma_bound(ma=ma):
    if ((ma >= 0.01) and (ma < 10)):
       return 0.0
    else:
       return -np.inf

M=pm.MCMC([ma,ma_bound])
M.sample(15000,5000,50)
```